# How to set default FB App setting from from Only Me to Friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've been unable to find answer in the FB / API documentation, i'm hoping someone can just point me in the right direction.

When I hit my test app it asks for me to grant it permissions, one of the drop-downs is set to "Only Me", so that any updates sent by that app will only be visible by me. I want it to be visible to my friends as well.

I have everything working, just need to know how to change that particular setting!

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are talking about Auth Dialog.
The [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#configure) says the default privacy setting follows the user's default privacy permissions.

> Default Activity Privacy: This field sets the Auth Dialog with a default action visibility setting which users can update when they authorize your app. By default, this value is set to None, which means your actions published will follow the user's default privacy permissions. A user's default privacy permissions, which is originally set by the user through the Privacy Settings page, applies whenever the user posts on Facebook. If the user changes it to Friends, the permission will be updated to friends only. If the user changes that to Public, your app activity will turn into public actions. Possible settings: None, Friends, Me only, or Public. The user can also change the Activity Privacy setting through the Auth Dialog.

So, basically the default value is up to each installing user.

Comment: Thank you Go Hagiwara for answering so quickly - that would make the most sense from a privacy point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Go to developer page. Apps > Your_APP_NAME > Settings > Permissions > Default Activity Privacy
and set whatever you want as default.if you set nothing then it will follow user defaults as answered by 'Go Hagiwara'

Answer (score 1):

This is now located in Apps > YOUR_APP_NAME > App Details > Configure App Centre Permissions > Default Activity Privacy

Comment: all I see is "Auth Token Parameter" and "API Version and App Center Permissions". Where is it?

Comment: It's no longer there - and I cannot find it anymore. Perhaps they have removed it?