# Facebook Open Graph actions privacy are set to Only Me

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, privacy

I have an app with Open Graph actions, that are approved by Facebook and live. The app is also live (not in developer sandbox mode). However, when I post the actions, they have their privacy setting set to "Only me", which is not what I want. When I change the post privacy to some other value (e.g. Friends) it works, my friends can see and interact with the post. I've tried to publish from multiple accounts, but they are all the same. How can I make the default Open Graph action privacy "Friends" instead of "Only me"?

I've also read that I could change the default post privacy of my app (as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12315480/811405), but couldn't figure out where it is.

Answer (score 3):

What permission you set when you first requested by app that, "The app would like to post on Facebook on behalf of you"?

Public or Friends or Only me? If you set permission to "only me", whenever you share, it only shares in private. You need to go to settings in your Facebook account and change the permission for that application again.

[Go to your Facebook Settings and select App in left pane](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications)

Select your application and change post option for your status updates. Hope it helps you.

Comment: It hasn't asked me anything, and I haven't selected anything.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Then how can you post using that app? Every app should ask for user permission in first start and only then you can post on Facebook using that app. I think you might have already given permission for that app to post on fb on behalf of you and thats why its not asking you anymore. Check your app in App settings in Facebook settings. If you see your app there, then you have already given permission.

Comment: Of course I've given permission in the beginning. But I haven't touched any privacy setting. I just tapped Okay and never went back.

Comment: That's what, If you want to change your post settings for your app, you can change it in App settings.

Comment: I know that I can change that. But as the develop of the app, I also know that I haven't changed anything by default but I want to know why its defaulted to "Only me". If it happened to me, it can happen to users of my app too and I (obviously) can't tell everyone to go to Facebook settings and change the privacy settings for my app.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu I understand the issue, but for me by default, If my default privacy settings are set to "friends" in Facebook (not in app), it automatically detects and the app asking me permission with the privacy value "friends".